# Update the array object by same id and result of arrobject value should be in sequential order in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, for-loop, object

Scenario:

I have array of objects `listarr`

by passing two paramaters `id` `orderval`, if same id exists, update the `orderval`.

and the result updatedList if have same value `orderval`, increment until its in sequential order.(ignore null)

```
const list = [
  { id: 10, orderval:null, color : 'red' },
  { id: 23, orderval: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, orderval: 4, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, orderval: 3, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, orderval: 2, color: 'indigo' },
];

var pid = 44; var pvalue = 2

Expected Output:

[
  { id: 10, orderval:null, color : 'red' },
  { id: 23, orderval: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, orderval: 4, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, orderval: 2, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, orderval: 3, color: 'indigo' },
]

Tried
// update the orderval based on same id
var updateList = list.map(e=> ({
  ...e,
  orderval: e.id===pid ? pvalue : e.orderval
}))

// apply for sequence
var result = updateList.map(i => ({
  ...e,
  orderval: (i.orderval !== pvalue && i.orderval > pvalue) ? (i.orderval || 0)+1 : i.orderval
}));
```

```
when  var pid = 44;
var pvalue = null; 

updateList will be
updateList = [
  { id: 10, orderval: null, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23, orderval: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, orderval: 4, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, orderval: null, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, orderval: 2, color: 'indigo' },
]; 

-> Increment will not happen here since no orderval is repeated

-> check if the orderval is in sequence (1,2, 3...) ignore null

if updatedList not in sequence, should return the list in sequence

[
  { id: 10, orderval: null, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23, orderval: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, orderval: 3, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, orderval: null, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, orderval: 2, color: 'indigo' },
];
```